# Insert list into SQLite3 cell

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to python and even newer to SQL and have just run into the following problem:

I want to insert a list (or actually, a list containing one or more dictionaries) into a single cell in my SQL database. This is one row of my data:

```
[a,b,c,[{key1: int, key2: int},{key1: int, key2: int}]]
```

As the number of dictionaries inside the lists varies and I want to iterate through the elements of the list later on, I thought it would make sense to keep it in one place (thus not splitting the list into its single elements). However, when trying to insert the list as it is, I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

How can this kind of list be inserted into a single cell of my SQL database?

Comment: would converting the list to a string format be acceptable ? for example JSON ?

Comment: You should show your insert code. With SQLite you would store that as a textual string, that's ok for storage but if you want to use SQL later on to query the data say for a specific key value then that's not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has no facility for a 'nested' column; you'd have to store your list as *text* or binary data blob; serialise it on the way in, deserialise it again on the way out.

How you serialise to text or binary data depends on your use-cases. JSON (via the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)) could be suitable if your lists and dictionaries consist only of text, numbers, booleans and `None` (with the dictionaries only using strings as keys). JSON is supported by a wide range of other languages, so you keep your data reasonably compatible. Or you could use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), which lets you serialise to a binary format and can handle just about anything Python can throw at it, but it's specific to Python.

You can then [register an adapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-adapters-to-store-additional-python-types-in-sqlite-databases) to handle converting between the serialisation format and Python lists:

```
import json
import sqlite3

def adapt_list_to_JSON(lst):
    return json.dumps(lst).encode('utf8')

def convert_JSON_to_list(data):
    return json.loads(data.decode('utf8'))

sqlite3.register_adapter(list, adapt_list_to_JSON)
sqlite3.register_converter("json", convert_JSON_to_list)
```

then connect with `detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES` and declare your column type as `json`, or use `detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES` and use `[json]` in a column alias (`SELECT datacol AS "datacol [json]" FROM ...`) to trigger the conversion on loading.